# PHP search and split an organized string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have some very basic PHP knowledge as I mostly do design work and some front end dev (and Wordpress on occasions) however with this latest WordPress project I need to do something a little more complicated. I'll spare you the details and explain a very simplified version of what I need done. I imagine this is probably something pretty simple however like I said my PHP knowledge is very basic and after a few hours of trying to figure it out, I didn't get anywhere.

**I have the following string:**

**"15, 23, 84, 69, 41"**

**I need a loop done in PHP that takes these numbers and displays them as:**

```
<div>15</div>
<div>23</div>
<div>84</div>
<div>69</div>
<div>41</div>
```

Obviously this loop would work for however many numbers I have in that string, weather it is 10 or 100. The code would actually have to print these values and not just store them in an array or anything like that, because I'm so crap at PHP it would take me a while to figure out how to get that array printed in a loop. So in other words for every number in that string it would have to have something like:

```
echo "<div>".$string_number."</div>";
```

Thank you very very much in advance to anyone that can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to `explode` them like

```
$str = "15, 23, 84, 69, 41";
$myArr = explode(',',$str);
foreach($myArr as $string_number) {
    echo "<div>".$string_number."</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can simple replace comma bye close div and open div ie:

```
$str="15, 23, 84, 69, 41";
echo "<div>".str_replace(", ", "</div><div>", $str)."</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

i write for you, try this

```
 $numbers        = '15, 23, 84, 69, 41';

$arr        = explode(',' ,$numbers);

foreach($arr as $l_numbers)
 {
     echo '<div>'.$l_numbers.'</div';
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It's basically the same as the above, however that answer was first. Thanks again for your help!